# How do I duplicate an edge?

Tags: geometry

I am trying to follow along with [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/O1ofHLNzAwc?t=30). I had to put its speed to 0.25 to be able to view it.

In this tutorial it is shown how the author selects an edge and then duplicates it and "scales" it while dragging.

I have taken some screenshots:

[image]

How does he do it, and what is this operation called?

Thank you!

Comment: Probably a bevel (Ctrl B)

Comment: If the "tutor" doesn't explain, then why bother following that "tutorial"?  It might be a bevel or extrusion. Hard to guess, For extrusion use the E key, for bevel Crl + B.

Comment: @susu Agreed, but he does exactely what I try just now, so it's super tempting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bevel, shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.  They then delete the resulting face to leave a gap between the planes.

[image]